# Remove specific bulk actions in Woocommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following code to remove bulk actions from the admin orders list, but I also need to remove/hide Export as XLSX, Mark Exported, Unmark Exported, and Duplicate. Does anyone know the action names for these?

```
    add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_shop_order_bulk_actions', 999 );
function custom_shop_order_bulk_actions( $actions ) {
    //Remove on hold and invoice from bulk actions
    unset( $actions['mark_on-hold'], $actions['invoice'] );
    return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the actions' names by inspecting the options inside of the ***#bulk-action-selector-top*** select element.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The only one I still can't get working is Duplicate. It show as 'duplicate', but when I use that tag it still doesn't hide it.